# does the following function have all directional derivatives?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$$xy\sin(\frac{1}{xy})$$
the function has partial derivatives at every point , but i wanted to know whether this function had directional derivatives at every point? for $x=0$ the function is $y\sin(\frac{1}{y})$ and for $y=0$ the function is $x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ and when both functions are $0$ the function has a value of $0$ .

Answer (score 0):

The best thing here if you want to know if there are directional derivatives everywhere that you simply try to calculate for an arbitrary point the directional derivative in an arbitrary direction. Look when it is possible and when not. This gives you the answer.